# QEMU networking: Host to Guest

Tags: debian, qemu, chroot, debootstrap, arm64

I want to connect a host(Debian 10 VM) to a qemu-guest (Debian on aarch64 ARM). I used to debootstrap tool to install a Debian root file system. Then I installed the qemu-user-static device on my host. I then chrooted to the guest's Debian. I can see that the host IP interfaces and settings are reflected in the guest as well.
But I aim to have a virtual network interface for my guest and connect to the host.

I have used QEMU in the past where I built an entire image along with the kernel and root file system and then used a bridged networking mode( which I thought did not involve "chrooting")

How can one achieve this in the current scenario? How different is the qemu-aarch64-static (qemu-user-static) tool to that of creating an image and emulating the device?
Could somebody give me some pointers?

Upon basic search, I found a lot of uses of the qemu-user-static tool for "running" a binary meant for a guest CPU on a host CPU — however very little information on networking such as hosts and guest machines.